# loss function numbers are looking different

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensor

I am new to deep learning however I know that usually, the loss function output would be in digits like 0.4, 0.6 something like that but the loss values I get look a bit different. Could some please tell me what is happening?

In the epoch, we can see the loss numbers are looking like this 4736.9226.

code:

#3d model

```
from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Dense, Flatten, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras import Input
# 3D Convolutional Model:
input_model=Input(shape=(10,250,250,1))
layer=Conv3D(32,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),activation='relu')(input_model)
layer=MaxPooling3D((2,2,2))(layer)
layer=Conv3D(64,(3,3,3),strides=(1,1,1),activation='relu')(layer)
layer=MaxPooling3D((2,2,2))(layer)
layer=BatchNormalization()(layer)
layer=Flatten()(layer)
layer=Dense(128,activation='relu')(layer)
layer=Dropout(0.1)(layer)
layer=Dense(64,activation='relu')(layer)
layer=Dropout(0.1)(layer)
layer=Dense(32,activation='relu')(layer)
layer=Dropout(0.1)(layer)
layer_output=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(layer)
model_3dConv=Model(input_model,layer_output)
model_3dConv.summary()

epoch:

    Epoch 1/10
    13/13 [==============================] - 91s 7s/step - loss: 4736.9226 - acc: 0.4918 - val_loss: 387258.4062 - val_acc: 0.5625
    Epoch 2/10
    13/13 [==============================] - 90s 7s/step - loss: 4021.6621 - acc: 0.5050 - val_loss: 246713.4844 - val_acc: 0.5625
    Epoch 3/10
    13/13 [==============================] - 89s 7s/step - loss: 3532.2977 - acc: 0.5936 - val_loss: 166724.2500 - val_acc: 0.5625

Whereas if I use 2d model this does not happen.
```

Update after 10 epoch:

```
[![Epoch 1/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 91s 7s/step - loss: 4736.9226 - acc: 0.4918 - val_loss: 387258.4062 - val_acc: 0.5625
Epoch 2/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 90s 7s/step - loss: 4021.6621 - acc: 0.5050 - val_loss: 246713.4844 - val_acc: 0.5625
Epoch 3/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 89s 7s/step - loss: 3532.2977 - acc: 0.5936 - val_loss: 166724.2500 - val_acc: 0.5625
Epoch 4/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 94s 7s/step - loss: 2712.2616 - acc: 0.5445 - val_loss: 112906.0078 - val_acc: 0.5625
Epoch 5/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 89s 7s/step - loss: 3779.4980 - acc: 0.5557 - val_loss: 75516.1641 - val_acc: 0.5625
Epoch 6/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 89s 7s/step - loss: 3778.8524 - acc: 0.5036 - val_loss: 53132.3477 - val_acc: 0.6875
Epoch 7/10
13/13 \[==============================\] - 91s 7s/step - loss: 3544.4086 - acc: 0.4869 - val_loss: 36817.3906 - val_acc: 0.6875][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason `the loss function output would be in digits like 0.4, 0.6 something`. I'm not sure what loss function your using here but for example the loss function [mse](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MSE) can be any positive number from `[0, inf)`. All the matters is your loss/val_loss should be going down each epoch, which it looks like your is doing.

Train for the full 10 epochs and check that val_loss is dropping and hopefully val_acc is going up.

Comment: please take a look at my updated epoch, my epoch stopped after 7 looks like the model is not learning more after that.

Comment: Your model went from val_loss of `387k to 36k` and val_acc of `56% to 69%` it is learning, quite a lot. You could make changes to achieve those results more efficiently, but I believe I answered your question.